# Why HttpContext.User.Identity and current user session object is null in MVC api controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, openid-connect

I am implementing custom authentication (corp and live using openid connect) in an existing mvc application.To implement this I am using a Filter class, Home Controller,Default Controller (API) and Account controller. Home Controller and Default controller are decorated like below code so that I can authorize user every page hits. When user access the site the home controller will be called by default and then filter will be called automatically, there I am authorizing user and setting the current context user like below code

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
        UserIdentities objIdentity = new ContextUser(userIdentity.EmailAddress);
        HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(objIdentity, null);
}
```

I am able to the value of identity (user email) in home controller like below code,

```
[AuthorizeFilter]
[ErrorFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller
{             
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string userEmailAddress=((ContextUser)HttpContext.User.Identity).EmailAddress;
        return View();
    }
```

}

Once after after page loaded I am calling default controller (API) method to get some data like below code by passing user email address there I am not able to the logged on user email address in default controller as I am always getting getting null value.

```
[HttpGet]
    public string GetOrg()
    {
        //getting null value
        string a = RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name; //null
        string b = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; //null
        string c = base.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;// null
        //I able to set the User Email Address session value in azurize filter but able to read in default controller.
        string d = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["UserEmail"].ToString();//null
        return repository.FetchOrg(a or b or c or d);
    }
```

seems all the values are resting somewhere in APi controller, not sure what I am missing and where I am wrong.Kindly let me know.

Comment: Have you tried using `filterContext.HttpContext` and `Controller.User` instead of `HttpContext.Current(.User)`?

Comment: yeah i tried that also, but same null value.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the session value after adding this below piece of code in Global.asax.cs file. Thanks team.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```